# Does a Brazilian, who does not need a visa to visit the UK, need a visa if not arriving from Brazil?

Tags: visas, uk, brazilian-citizens

I'm Brazilian and I have a Blue Card from working in Germany. I want to visit London. Do I need a visa to do that? I know that Brazilians don't need a visa to visit but, since I'm not travelling there from Brazil, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you're flying from. Either you need a visa for the UK or you don't.

Like you said, you can enter without a visa, and can usually stay for up to 6 months.